# Configuring Lubuntu to run a script when LXDE starts

Tags: scripts

I'm using Lubuntu and LXDE. How can I configure it such that when LXDE starts, it runs the following script to turn off the trackpad:

```
xinput disable 14
```

I tried to make the files ~/.config/autostart/ as

```
[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Exec=xinput disable 14
```

and the file .desktop as

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=xinput disable 14
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

Also, I didn't found anything suitable in the program `lxsession-edit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Lubuntu 13.10, edit `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`. Add the appropriate command on a separate line to the end of the existing file. If such a file doesn't exist, create it with Leafpad or nano.

By the way, are you sure about `xinput disable 14`? Based on `man xinput`, it appears that `xinput --disable 14` may be correct.

--enable device
           Enable the device.  This  call  is  equivalent  to  xinput
           --set-prop device "Device Enabled" 1

--disable device
           Disable  the  device.  This  call  is equivalent to xinput
           --set-prop device "Device Enabled" 0

---

**Edit**: I asked about `--` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105364/15760).

Comment: Thanks! The solution was to create the file autostart. At least the `xinput disable 14` works in my computer system.

Comment: Okay, I thought you'd need `--disable` and not plain `disable`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I have come across. There is a GUI, started from a terminal command to configure startup apps in LXDE

```
lxsession-edit
```

Documentation seems unclear on it's current state. The ability to add your own custom command to that list may or may not have been added to your version. If you are unable to add your own command to that list, try this older method.
Add a .desktop file to your ~/.config/autostart directory. Create it if not there
Add these 3 lines to the .desktop file and save it

```
[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Exec=xinput disable 14
```

Optionally you may wish to use these directives, in that .desktop file:

```
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

Unfortunately wiki.lxde.org is borked, atm

Comment: I tried both methods but it looks like this does not work. (trackpad still works.)