# How do I execute terminal commands by clicking an icon?

Tags: command-line, executable

I'm trying to set up my sister's laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 running the LDXE shell. The only issue is, on boot, the wifi is disabled by default and I can't seem to reactivate it except with these terminal commands:

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

I'm wondering if there's a way for me to put these two into an executable, and just have her click that to start the wifi instead of opening the terminal and possibly forgetting the command.

Comment: Why not use a startup script for this, so that it runs automatically on boot ? Here's how to do that: [Configuring Lubuntu to run a script when LXDE starts](http://askubuntu.com/a/391212). If you _do_ want to use an icon, here's how you can do _that_:  [How to execute sh script from a desktop shortcut?](http://askubuntu.com/a/299073)

Comment: Hi Brenden, Please mention if you manage.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative way to run the commands at start up, you can set up those lines without the sudo in `/etc/rc.local` and it should execute them during start up.